# Android webview, built with cordova, will not connect to node server in release build but will connect in debug build

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, webview, socket.io

We have a websocket connection using socket.io through a server side node script. We are trying to establish through android webview. However, the debug build will get the page, but the release build will not load the page.

We are trying to load the page via an html javascript include, and it works on the android browser as well as ios webview. Here is an example:

```
<script src="https://example.com:8081/page.js"></script>
```

Comment: How have you signed the certificate for `https` connections? Is it self-signed or is it from a competent authority like `Verisign`. I have seen on stackoverflow that `self-signed` certificates do not work.

Comment: Its from a competent authority (comodo) and the other https certifications being accessed through Apache work fine. And we are using the same certificate for the node server.

Comment: This is an issue for me as well. Has anyone figured it out?